# Why iCloud Drive takes up space though there are no content there at all

Tags: icloud

As you can see there is no content at all in iCloud Drive subfolders, but the size it takes is 1.7 GB. How?

[image]

Comment: Did you have view invisibles files turned on?

Comment: I do not have invisible files.

Comment: How do you know. Any file or folder which starts with a . is invisible.  Most directories have a file whose file name starts with a period.

Comment: Updated screen shot, now the hidden files are show also. For development I used CloudKit, may it cause it? But 1.8 GB?

Comment: did you have any invisible directories?  Many applications create an invisible directory on installation?  Were any of the invisibles of a significant size?  I have the editor Atom on my mac. The directory .atom is half a gig...

Comment: You can see hidden files folder on screen shot. There are no.

Comment: The files might be in recently deleted if deleted from ios devices. They can be seen at the iCloud website. You can use some terminal code to list all the files under the directory  `ls -R ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/`